# ETL log collected using Windows Performance Recorder shows blank stack frames

Tags: windows, performance, perfmon, wpa

I have collected a ETL log for a CPU spike using WPR but the hot path is ending with blank stack frames. Can anyone please explain what happened ?

[Screenshot of Windows performance analyzer showing blank frames](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oj79b.png)